# using ILocationManager in Android

Tags: android, gps, android-location, aidl

I tried decompiling an app posted on the playstore and the app has this code:

`import android.location.ILocationManager`

I cant replicate this on my app I get the error cannot resolve symbol. The app i'm  looking at can be installed as a system app for some functions to work. Maybe this has something to do with it being a system app?

How can I get the ILocationManager class?

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but ILocationManager isn't actually a class, it's an interface. Therefore you can't instantiate it. The interface definition isn't in the android sources, but Google Sources has a version of it: [ILocationManager.aidl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/ILocationManager.aidl)

You can read about Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL) [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html).

Classes using the ILocationManager are among others **Geocoder** and **LocationManager** - have a look at them. It is used for communicating with a service on the Internet; in the case of Geocoder, to communicate with the google geocoder service.